# Scala - Define a function with the following signature that searches for element n of a list

Tags: scala

the initial code is:

```scala
def nth(list: List[Int], x: Int) = ???
```

and I try this:

```scala
def nth(list: List[Int], n: Int): Option[Int] = 
  list match { 
    case h :: t if n > 0 => nth(t, n - 1) 
    case _ => list
  }
```

but it doesn't work

thank you for helping me I try the previous code

Comment: `case _ => list` is `List[Int]` instead of `Option[Int]`, you also aren't handling the case when e.g 2 element list will be asked for 4th element.

Answer (score 1):

First of all since the return type is `Option[Int]` you need to return `None` when list has less then n (or n-1 depended on `n` being zero or one based) elements, then you need to return `Some` when you reach the `nth` element. Check out the scaladoc for [`Option`](https://scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Option.html) type.

For example simple recursive solution can look like this (zero based `n`):

```scala
def nth(list: List[Int], n: Int): Option[Int] =
  list match {
    case h :: t if n > 0  => nth(t, n - 1)
    case h :: t if n == 0 => Some(h)
    case _                => None
  }
```